# Particle distance vs Point distance

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In my study of quantum mechanics, one thing has being troubling me. The square modulus of the wavefunction of some point x in space, at a given specific time, is considered to be the probability density function of a particle being near that point.

Now my question is based on the two identical particles system. Given that both particles share a universal wave function, one which is composed of both particle coordinates ( do not be concerned with the states of the particles), say for particle 1(p1) we have point a and for particle 2(p2) we have point b, and the distance between a,b is known and constant. Since there exists a probability that p1 is near a, and p2 is near b, is it fair to conclude that at a specific moment in time, there is a probability that the distance between a,b is equal to the distance between p1 and p2;thereby implying that p1 and p2 may be closer to each other or further away from each other than would a,b allow, since their respective positions is entirely dependent on their respective wave functions?

Think of it this way in classical mechanics we associate an object with a point in space, and we note that there is a distance between two points in space and a distance between two objects...

Is the distance between two quanta the same as the points associated with them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. QM is probabilistic so yes, if you abritrarily choose two points, in general the two particles could be closer together or farther apart compared to the distance between the points.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.